# Switch Bootstrap Icons on change of input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm working on a password input, and here is the user's situation.

- I want a red cross when the password has not the conditions.
- I want a green cross when the password is good enough.

Here is the code (pay only attention at the If structure), I'll explain the problem bellow.

```
    $('#id_password.form-control').on('change', function(){
    var inputVal = $(this).val(); //Quand on appelle this, on récupère la valeur dans laquelle elle est utilisée.
    var passwordReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}$/;
    if(!passwordReg.test(inputVal) || ($(this).val() == "")){
        $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
        $(this).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok");
    }
    else{
        $(this).after('<span style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>')
        $(this).removeClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove");
    }
});
```

There's two problems to my code :

- My icons are duplicating each time I change focus. I tried the .one() method but it invocates my method only once (obviously).
- I can't swap the Icons when the user corrects himself his password. I saw the .removeClass() method but not efficient.

If you have some Ideas or if you want more details, I am open, I want correct my mistakes in order to notice it =)

Thank you for taking your time, and have a nice day in code =)

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3wctaf1n/ Here is the code, It doesn't work instead on my server, but you have a visual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're removing the class from the previously added `span`, you're not removing the `span` itself. You can do that by using `.next('span').remove()`, like this:

```
$('#id_password.form-control').on('change', function(){
    var $input = $(this);
    var inputVal = $input.val();
    var passwordReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}$/;

    $input.next('span').remove();
    if ($input.val() == "" || !passwordReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $input.after('<span style="color: red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
    }
    else {
        $input.after('<span style="color: green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>')
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3wctaf1n/2/)

Comment: It works, thank you but I don't like give my code and waiting for an experiment developer corrects my solution. Can you explain the .next() method ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your first sentence. The `next()` method documentation is here: http://api.jquery.com/next

Comment: the after function appends at each key press a new span ,what the `next()` function does it helps to select the all the previous appended spans and `remove()` removes them  so you can add the corect one based on the input

Comment: Thank you, sorry my english is bad. I wanted to say that I don't like to give my code and waiting for a correction when I have some bugs ^^'

Comment: i use a different approach by going up a level in the dom selecting the parent element of the form with `parent()` and using `find()` we select the previous appended spans and remove them, see my answer :)

Comment: @madalinivascu I understand your approach, I will test it with another form. I'm learning a lot with your help =)

Comment: I can't give answer for both ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 $('#id_password.form-control').on('input', function(){

   $(this).parent().find('.glyphicon').remove();//remove the icons each time the input changes


    var inputVal = $(this).val(); //Quand on appelle this, on récupère la valeur dans laquelle elle est utilisée.
    var passwordReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}$/;
    if(!passwordReg.test(inputVal) || ($(this).val() == "")){
        $(this).after('<span style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>');
    }
    else{
        $(this).after('<span style="color:green" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
    }
});
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/L3z2sdLr/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using `form-group` etc and look a bit prettier w/ Bootstrap:

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p1rchywb/5/

HTML

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <label class="control-label" for="password">Enter Your Password</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password">
  <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("#password").on("change", function() {
  var passwordReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{8,}$/;
  if($(this).val() !== "" || passwordReg.test($(this).val()) ) {
    $(this).next().removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");
  } else {
    $(this).next().addClass("glyphicon-remove").removeClass("glyphicon-ok"); 
  }
});
```